# a:focus doesn't work in ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, focus

a:focus doesn't work only in IE.
So I'm looking the way to fix this problem, but didn't find for now.

```
<div class="city-selection">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" tabindex="1"><span>Тольятти</span></a></li>
                            <li class="city-right-text"><a href="#" tabindex="2"><span>Самара</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
.city-selection ul li a:focus {
    background-image: url("/img/button.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 3px 0px;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: is it working in other browser? can u add jsfiddle for that?

Comment: Yes, it works in other browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do that by javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('city-selection').focus();
```

Comment: Thank's. It works, I'm new in JS and I just starting to study it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a [link](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fixing-focus-in-internet-explorer/) about fixing :focus in ie. 

Code to check whether browser supports 'focus' from that link:

```
var focusIsSupported = (function(){

// Create an anchor + some styles including ':focus'.
// Focus the anchor, test if style was applied,
// if it was then we know ':focus' is supported.

var ud = 't' + +new Date(),
    anchor = $('<a id="' + ud + '" href="#"/>').css({top:'-999px',position:'absolute'}).appendTo('body'),
    style = $('<style>#'+ud+'{font-size:10px;}#'+ud+':focus{font-size:1px !important;}</style>').appendTo('head'),
    supported = anchor.focus().css('fontSize') !== '10px';
anchor.add(style).remove();
return supported;

})();
```

Also have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5K4x/).

Comment: I don't understand this code. Can you explain on my code example?

Comment: Did you check the link I provided? It is explained well there. Just add the jquery code; there is nothing to change in your css. There is also a demo in that page. Check if that works in ie. Also make sure that you have declared <!DOCTYPE> in your page and that the css is in an external stylesheet.

Comment: @sanchahous I've also added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5K4x/). Please check if that works on IE. It seems to be working on my device.

Comment: Thank's you. It is help full